# How to increase a variable shared by all objects in a class by 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

How would I make a function called nextyear() that increases all the animals age by 1?

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self, age):
    self.age=age
animal1 = Animal (5)
animal2 = Animal (7)
animal3 = Animal (3)
```

Comment: you want to increase _all_ the animage ages? in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use a class variable and a property:

```
class Animal:
    year = 0

    def __init__(self, age):
        self._age = age - self.__class__.year

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age + self.__class__.year

    @classmethod
    def next_year(cls):
        cls.year += 1


animal1, animal2, animal3 = Animal(5), Animal(7), Animal(3)

for animal in (animal1, animal2, animal3):
    print(animal.age)

print("Next year:")
Animal.next_year()
for animal in (animal1, animal2, animal3):
    print(animal.age)
```

Comment: Good idea.  Using a class variable is shared across all classes.  Using the static method to alter it makes for clean api.  Not stray functions outside.

Comment: This was clean!

Comment: Of all the answers, this is probably the cleanest. I don't like the idea of maintaining a list of instances, and iterating over each defeats the purpose.

Comment: To avoid hardcording the class name `Animal`, consider a `@classmethod` instead of a static method. Then   `def next_year(cls):  cls.year += 1`.  For other the other instance methods, use `self.__class__.year` instead of `Animal.year`.

Comment: Sure.  I see you added this part `self._age = age - self.__class__.year` to the `__init__` method.  Can you share your rationale?  Why not `self._age = age` alone?

Comment: @pylang sure, let's say in year 2 if you were to add a new animal of age 1 say `bob = Animal(1)` you would want `bob._age` to be `-1` so when you got `bob.age` it would return `-1+2 = 1`. If we did not change the `__init__` bob would show as being 3, not 1, as he was born on year 2.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to keep a list of the animals who are instances of the class, and add a class method to increase the age:

```
class Animal:
    _animals = []
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
        self._animals.append(self)
        print(self._animals)

    @classmethod
    def one_year_more(cls):
        for animal in cls._animals:
            animal.age += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm an animal and I'm {} years old".format(self.age)

animal1 = Animal (5)
animal2 = Animal (7)
animal3 = Animal (3)

print(animal1)
# I'm an animal and I'm 5 years old

Animal.one_year_more()

print(animal1)
print(animal2)
# I'm an animal and I'm 6 years old
# I'm an animal and I'm 8 years old
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a method to the class Animal to increase the age:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age=age

    def increase_age(self):
        self.age+=1
```

Then keep a list of your animals when you create them:

```
animals = []

animals.append(Animal(5))
animals.append(Animal(7))
animals.append(Animal(3))
```

Use a loop to increase the age:

```
for animal in animals:
    animal.increase_age()

for animal in animals:
    print(animal.age)
```

Outputs: 6 8 4

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to the class:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age=age
    def add_year(self, years=1):
        self.age += years         # adds 1 year by default (accepts a param)

animal1 = Animal (5)
animal2 = Animal (7)
animal3 = Animal (3)

for i in (animal1, animal2, animal3):
    i.add_year()

print(animal1.age)
```

Returns

```
6
```